# Excel VBA Email Rows to a Single Recipient

Tags: vba, email, excel, automation

I have a worksheet that tracks invoices and I am trying to generate an auto-emailer that if a cell in column 12 contains AUTOEMAIL it will combine all of the rows with a similar email address which I've generated using a TRIM function. It will pull all of the like rows (Email Addresses based on column 15) into a LotusNotes Email. Ron De Bruin has some fantastic examples on his site. I attempted to write a loop which attempts to loop through and copy all rows based on an email address. When I go to run, the code does nothing but no errors are presented. There are instances online of this done in Outlook, but they don't apply to LotusNotes as the issue is late vs early binding. I'm newer to VBA automation as well.

```
    Sub Send_Data()
Dim noSession As Object, noDatabase As Object, noDocument As Object
Dim vaRecipient As Variant
Dim rnBody As Range
Dim Data As DataObject

Const stSubject As String = "TEST"
Const stMsg As String = "TEST"
Const stPrompt As String = "Please select the range:"

lastrow = Range("N" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
For Each Cell In Range("N8:N" & lastrow)
If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("N8:N" & Cell.row), Cell) = 1 Then
If Cells(Cell.row, 11) = "AUTOEMAIL" Then

rnBody = "Hello" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
ActiveCell.EntireRow.Select


On Error Resume Next

'The user canceled the operation.
If rnBody Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

On Error GoTo 0

'Instantiate Lotus Notes COM's objects.
Set noSession = CreateObject("Notes.NotesSession")
Set noDatabase = noSession.GETDATABASE("", "")

'Make sure Lotus Notes is open and available.
If noDatabase.IsOpen = False Then noDatabase.OPENMAIL

'Create the document for the e-mail.
Set noDocument = noDatabase.CreateDocument

 'Copy the selected range into memory.
 rnBody.Copy

 'Retrieve the data from then copied range.
 Set Data = New DataObject
 Data.GetFromClipboard

 'Add data to the mainproperties of the e-mail's document.
 With noDocument
   .Form = "Memo"
   .SendTo = vaRecipient
   .Subject = stSubject
   'Retrieve the data from the clipboard.
   .Body = stMsg & " " & Data.GetText
    .SaveMessageOnSend = True
 End With

 ' SEND EMAIL
 With noDocument
   .PostedDate = Now()
   .Send 0, vaRecipient
End With

' REMOVE FROM MEMORY
Set noDocument = Nothing
Set noDatabase = Nothing
Set noSession = Nothing


'SWITCH BACK TO EXCEL
AppActivate "Microsoft Excel"

'EMPTY COPY-PAST CLIPBOARD
Application.CutCopyMode = False
' DISPLAYS TO USER IF SUCCESSFUL
MsgBox "Complete!", vbInformation
  End If
 End If
Next Cell
End Sub
```

Comment: What have you tried to narrow down the issue?  You could debug the vba to see if it is getting to thsy line - or try a simpler version - that is, sending an email, but without the code to combine the emails, etc, just send to a hardcoded email or get it from a single cell in the Excel sheet.

Comment: Ron de Bruins send unformatted data works correctly with my sheet but relies on a VBA Array of email addresses. I realized that above I have not set vaRecipient but I set it manually to my email address and I still am unable to see any output :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set the email body range as a Prompt Box where the user could highlight the cells and then another prompt box in which it asked for the email that was created using a TRIM() function. I realized that the way the code was set-up would not allow for what I wanted to do. The new method works quite well

Treevar